# How to send post parameters dynamically (or in loop) in OKHTTP 3.x in android?

Tags: android, okhttp

I am using OKHTTP 3.x version. I want to post multiple  parameters and would like to add the params in a loop.
I know that in version 2.x , I can use FormEncodingBuilder and add params to it in loop and then from it create a request body.
But In 3.x , the class has been removed.

Here is my current code :

```
RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("Param1", value1)
            .add("Param2", value2)
            .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("url")
            .post(formBody)
            .build();
```

Now I want to add 5 params but in a loop i.e create request body by building formbody in a loop.
Like I wrote above, I know how to do it in OKHTTP version 2.x but I am using version  3.x.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I have not done any hands-on this but first time you can make JsonObject containing 5 Params & pass that single JsonObject to your formBody be a se it seems formBody accepts Object.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

```
FormBody.Builder formBuilder = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("key", "123");

// dynamically add more parameter like this:
formBuilder.add("phone", "000000");

RequestBody formBody = formBuilder.build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://aaa.com")
                .post(formBody)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 18):

Imports

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
```

Code:

```
// HashMap with Params
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put( "Param1", "A" );
params.put( "Param2", "B" );

// Initialize Builder (not RequestBody)
FormBody.Builder builder = new FormBody.Builder();

// Add Params to Builder
for ( Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet() ) {
    builder.add( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
}

// Create RequestBody
RequestBody formBody = builder.build();

// Create Request (same)
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url( "url" )
        .post( formBody )
        .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version

```
/**
 * <strong>Uses:</strong><br/>
 * <p>
 * {@code
 * List<Pair<String, String>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();}
 * <br/>
 * {@code pairs.add(new Pair<>("key1", "value1"));}<br/>
 * {@code pairs.add(new Pair<>("key2", "value2"));}<br/>
 * {@code pairs.add(new Pair<>("key3", "value3"));}<br/>
 * <br/>
 * {@code postToServer("http://www.example.com/", pairs);}<br/>
 * </p>
 *
 * @param url
 * @param pairs List of support.V4 Pair
 * @return response from server in String format
 * @throws Exception
 */
public String postToServer(String url, List<Pair<String, String>> pairs) throws Exception {
    okhttp3.OkHttpClient client = new okhttp3.OkHttpClient();
    okhttp3.Request.Builder builder = new okhttp3.Request.Builder().url(url);

    if (pairs != null) {
        okhttp3.FormBody.Builder postData = new okhttp3.FormBody.Builder();
        for (Pair<String, String> pair : pairs) {
            postData.add(pair.first, pair.second);
        }
        builder.post(postData.build());
    }
    okhttp3.Request request = builder.build();
    okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
        throw new IOException(response.message() + " " + response.toString());
    }
    return response.body().string();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try something like that :

```
RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder();
for(...;...;...) {
   formBody.add(...)
}
formBody.build();
```

the rest of your code seems good.
Hope it will work :) !

Comment: It does not work, already tried. FormBody.Builder does not return a RequestBody.
Incompatible types.
:(